# Is it possible to take action on checking/unchecking a checkbox with Django?

Tags: django

I have a simple checkmark box on detail.html. When I press the "Send" button, it takes me to results.html. In Django, is it possible to bypass the "Send" button and get directed to results.html when I check and uncheck the checkbox?

Here's detail.html
    {% csrf_token %}

results.html looks like this:

```
<ul>
{% for choice in poll %}
    <li>{{ choice }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

views.py looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def handle(request):
artists = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
    artists = request.POST.getlist('artists')
return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'poll': artists})
```

urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^detail/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', {'template': 'polls/detail.html'}),
    url(r'^results/$', 'polls.views.handle'),
)
```

Comment: you can implement this in JavaScript and send the form data in an AJAX POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Django. You need to write some Javascript that listens to the `onclick` event of the checkbox and changes `location.href` accordingly.

Comment: I figured I'd have to use Javascript but thought maybe there's a way to do it in Django without Javascript

Comment: There's no possible way to do it without Javascript, in Django or not. Browsers simply won't do anything when a checkbox is clicked unless you tell them to do so, ie with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Actions taking place after the page loads can not be handled by Django. Use Javascript to talk to Django using an AJAX request.